# Checkout from non-working branch and want to rebase to master

Tags: git

I should've done `git checkout -b "test"` from `master`, but I accidentally checked out from `branch1`, so now all of the non-working code from `branch1` is clustered into my `test` branch.

I think the correct command is `git rebase master`, which updates my current branch's parent branch to be `master`, but it doesn't seem to be working. Is this the right command?

Comment: Are there commits and/or uncommitted changes in test and/or branch1 before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a little confused as to the structure of the your repository before and after the creation of the "test" branch.  I am assuming that "branch1" is branching off of master, and now "test" is sitting on top of "branch1" like this:

```
  master      branch1      test, HEAD
- - * - - * - - * - - * - - *
    a     b     c     d     e
```

If this is the case then you can run `git rebase --onto master branch1 test` and that will change your repository to:

```
  master      branch1
- - * - - * - - *
    a\    b     c
      \                    test
       - - - - - - - * - - * 
                     d'    e'
```

If that is not the original situation, then I am confused.

Comment: This method (using `git rebase` with `--onto master` to set the target point, limiting to-be-copied commits via the name `branch1`, and rebasing commits that are contained within `test` and moving `test` when done) will work in nearly all situations, in fact.  Well, given the starting conditions in the original post, of course.

Comment: I should've drawn out the structure in the question to provide more context, but yes, that's what I was looking for. My `test` branch now has `master` as its parent branch.

Comment: Glad I assumed correctly :).  
On a slightly related note, because of the up votes and accept, I reached 200 rep, which got me a +100 rep bonus for association.  It was a real surprise to see +435 rep in my notification area (300 was for other SE sites).  - made my day

Comment: Anytime! Thanks for helping out!